# Symbol table has missing items in c

Tags: c, string, header, symbols, elf

i wanted to write a code that does store symbol table and string table from the raw .elf file. My code here accomplishes that but it has missing addresses and names:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// ELF header structure
typedef struct {
    uint8_t e_ident[16];
    uint16_t e_type;
    uint16_t e_machine;
    uint32_t e_version;
    uint64_t e_entry;
    uint64_t e_phoff;
    uint64_t e_shoff;
    uint32_t e_flags;
    uint16_t e_ehsize;
    uint16_t e_phentsize;
    uint16_t e_phnum;
    uint16_t e_shentsize;
    uint16_t e_shnum;
    uint16_t e_shstrndx;
} Elf64_Ehdr;

// Section header structure
typedef struct {
    uint32_t sh_name;
    uint32_t sh_type;
    uint64_t sh_flags;
    uint64_t sh_addr;
    uint64_t sh_offset;
    uint64_t sh_size;
    uint32_t sh_link;
    uint32_t sh_info;
    uint64_t sh_addralign;
    uint64_t sh_entsize;
} Elf64_Shdr;

// Symbol table entry structure
typedef struct {
    uint32_t st_name;
    uint8_t st_info;
    uint8_t st_other;
    uint16_t st_shndx;
    uint32_t st_value; // normally it was uint64_t
    uint64_t st_size;
    uint32_t st_name2; // Extended name field
} Elf64_Sym;

Elf64_Sym* symbol_table;
char* string_table;
uint64_t stringSize;
size_t num_symbols;

struct SymbolEntry {
    char name[256];
    unsigned long address;
};

// Comparison function for sorting symbols based on their addresses
int compare_symbols(const void* a, const void* b) {
    const Elf64_Sym* symbol_a = (const Elf64_Sym*)a;
    const Elf64_Sym* symbol_b = (const Elf64_Sym*)b;

    if (symbol_a->st_value < symbol_b->st_value) return -1;
    if (symbol_a->st_value > symbol_b->st_value) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int findTables(){
    
    FILE* file = fopen("trace.elf", "rb");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the ELF header
    Elf64_Ehdr elf_header;
    if (fread(&elf_header, sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr), 1, file) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading ELF header\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the section header table offset from the ELF header
    fseek(file, elf_header.e_shoff, SEEK_SET);

    // Read the section header table
    Elf64_Shdr section_headers[elf_header.e_shnum];
    if (fread(section_headers, sizeof(Elf64_Shdr), elf_header.e_shnum, file) != elf_header.e_shnum) {
        printf("Error reading section headers\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    // Find the symbol table and the associated string table (for symbol names)
    Elf64_Shdr* symbol_table_header = NULL;
    Elf64_Shdr* string_table_header = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < elf_header.e_shnum; i++) {
        if (section_headers[i].sh_type == 0x2) { // SHT_SYMTAB
            symbol_table_header = &section_headers[i];
        } else if (section_headers[i].sh_type == 0x3) { // SHT_STRTAB
            string_table_header = &section_headers[i];
        }

        if (symbol_table_header && string_table_header) {
            break; // Both tables found, exit the loop
        }
    }

    if (!symbol_table_header || !string_table_header) {
        printf("Symbol table or string table not found\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate the number of symbols in the symbol table
    num_symbols = symbol_table_header->sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym);

    // Read the symbol table
    symbol_table = (Elf64_Sym*)malloc(symbol_table_header->sh_size);
    if (!symbol_table) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for symbol table\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(file, symbol_table_header->sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
    if (fread(symbol_table, sizeof(Elf64_Sym), num_symbols, file) != num_symbols) {
        printf("Error reading symbol table\n");
        free(symbol_table);
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the string table
    string_table = (char*)malloc(string_table_header->sh_size);
    if (!string_table) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for string table\n");
        free(symbol_table);
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(file, string_table_header->sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
    if (fread(string_table, 1, string_table_header->sh_size, file) != string_table_header->sh_size) {
        printf("Error reading string table\n");
        free(symbol_table);
        free(string_table);
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    stringSize = string_table_header->sh_size;
    fclose(file);
}

void printTables(){
    printf("Address\t\tName\n");
    printf("-------\t\t----\n");

    // Print all symbols with their addresses and names
    for (size_t j = 0; j < num_symbols; j++) {
        // Check if the symbol name is valid (inside the string table)
        if (symbol_table[j].st_name < stringSize) {
            char* symbol_name = &string_table[symbol_table[j].st_name];
            printf("0x%08x\t%s\n", symbol_table[j].st_value, symbol_name);
        }
    }
}

void freeSpaces(){
    free(symbol_table);
    free(string_table);
}

int main() {

    if(findTables() == 1){
        printf("Exiting...");
        return 0;
    }
    // Sort the symbol table based on addresses
    qsort(symbol_table, num_symbols, sizeof(Elf64_Sym), compare_symbols);

    printTables();
    
    freeSpaces();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's some of the output of the code for trace.elf:

```
0x004016d0      __do_global_dtors_aux
0x00401ac1      trace_return_values
0x00401b0c      foo
0x00401b36      main
0x00401b50      handle_zhaoxin
0x00401fb0      get_common_indices.constprop.0
0x00402df0      __libc_start_main_impl
```

but when use the "nm -n trace.elf" command and get the symbol table that way the same section is:

```
00000000004016d0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000401710 t frame_dummy
0000000000401745 T get_address
0000000000401ac1 T trace_return_values
0000000000401b0c T foo
0000000000401b21 T bar
0000000000401b36 T main
0000000000401b50 t handle_zhaoxin
0000000000401d20 t handle_amd
0000000000401ed0 t call_fini
0000000000401f10 t __libc_start_call_main
```

as you can see some addresses and names is missing in the first output. especially "bar". Is my code wrong or there are other problems?

Comment: You will get more helpful feedback, if you provide textual information as text instead of as pictures of text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> symbol table and string table from the raw .elf file.

You should be aware that an ELF file with `.e_type` of `ET_DYN` or `ET_EXEC` may have *two* symbol tables -- the "regular" and the "dynamic" one:

```
readelf -WS /tmp/a.out | egrep 'symtab|dynsym'
  [ 7] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000000000000410 000410 000120 18   A  8   1  8
  [30] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 003080 000468 18     31  21  8
```

and up to *three* `SYMTAB` sections, e.g.

```
 readelf -WS /tmp/a.out | egrep 'STRTAB'
  [ 8] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000000530 000530 000139 00   A  0   0  1
  [31] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 0034e8 00035a 00      0   0  1
  [32] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 003842 00012c 00      0   0  1
```

Your code is wrong in that it picks up the first `STRTAB` section it finds, which may not the the one `SYMTAB` is actually referencing.

For example, for the executable above your code will pick `.dynstr` instead of `.strtab` (which is what you intended).

After you locate the `SYMTAB` section, you must look at `symbol_table_header->sh_link` to find the correct `STRTAB` section that your `SYMTAB` references (the `sh_link` is the 9th column above; you can see that `.dynsym` links to section 8, and `.symtab` to section 31).

---

P.S. Unless your program is being built on a system without `/usr/include/elf.h`, it's a really bad idea™ to do this:

```
// ELF header structure
typedef struct {
    uint8_t e_ident[16];
    uint16_t e_type;
    uint16_t e_machine;
...
```

You should use the system-provided `<elf.h>` instead.

And if you are building this on a system without `<elf.h>`, it is *still* a very bad idea to do this:

```
 if (section_headers[i].sh_type == 0x2) { // SHT_SYMTAB
```

Instead, write code like this:

```
#ifndef SHT_SYMTAB
#define SHT_SYMTAB 2
#endif
...

 if (section_headers[i].sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {
...
```